Resources for learning to analytically solve systems of nonlinear differential equations
Recently, I've been learning about differential equations, and in doing so, I came across this system:
$$\large \dfrac{d}{dt}{{x}\choose{y}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5\\\\
7 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \cdot {{\arctan(x)}\choose{\arctan(y)}}$$
I know that the system is unlikely to be solvable due to its nonlinearity, but I want to try anyways. The problem is that I haven't been able to find any resources that teach methods for  analytically solving systems of / higher order nonlinear ODEs.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could direct me on where I can learn that!
(For reference, I've completed an introductory course on ODEs, covering first-order ODEs, second-order linear ODEs, systems of linear ODEs with constant coefficients & Laplace transforms)
Advice regarding this specific ODE would also be appreciated. The only thing I've successfully done is find a power-series solution.

@Moo First off, thank you for your thorough answer!
Is there a way to check if a given ODE has a closed form solution, or are you just assuming that there isn't one?

@Moo I'm so sorry for bothering you, but do you know what happened to the comments? I forgot to write down your answer, and I can't find your comments anymore...
